# Model showing null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, model, nunit

I am writting unit test cases. I am using nunit and rhino mock.

Method which is i am testing is

```
        public ActionResult Details()
    {
        EmployeeDTO employee = this.EmployeeService.GetLoggedInEmployee();
        EmployeeModel model = assembler.ToEmployeeModel(employee);
        model.Title = GetEmployeeNameTitle(employee);
        model.Controller = "LoanOfficer";
        model.SelectedTab = MainNavTabs.LoanOfficerDetails;
        return View(model);
    }
```

And test case written is

```
        [Test]
    public void TestDetails()
    {
        EmployeeDTO employee = new EmployeeDTO();
        EmployeeService.Stub(a => a.GetLoggedInEmployee()).Return(employee);
        EmployeeModel model = new EmployeeModel{ Title = UtilityTests.Title, };
        assembler.Stub(b => b.ToEmployeeModel(employee)).Return(model);
        controller.Details();
        // Assert
    }
```

I have done

```
        private ILoanModelAssembler loanAssembler;
    loanAssembler = TestUtility.DynamicMock<ILoanModelAssembler>();
```

but still here model is null ? Is there is any way to correct it in test method?

Comment: *where* is it null please?

Comment: Your code uses assembler, your unit test uses loanAssembler...

Comment: Hey Andras Zoltan, i debug on model then it will show null.

Comment: Hey Roy Dictus, Still showing error.

Answer (score 1):

It's null because your you're not taking control of the actual instance of EmployeeService from within your test. How is your EmployeeService dependency being added to the controller? Is it an interface? You would need it to be an interface so that Rhino Mocks can mock it and you would need to inject it into the constructor of your controller so that you can inject your mocked instance into your test. Something like this:

```
private IEmployeeService employeeService;

public EmployeeController(IEmployeeService employeeService)
{
    this.employeeService = employeeService;
}
```

Then in your test you can say:

```
var employeeServiceStub = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IEmployeeService>();
var employee = new EmployeeDTO();
employeeServiceStub.Stub(a => a.GetLoggedInEmployee()).Return(employee);
```